# iOS 5 sqlite slowdown

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

Why is sqlite so much slower in iOS 5 that previous versions? There have been several posts with this as the core issue, and the solutions revolve around either optimizing your sqlite db or query, or switching to something else. None, however, have addressed the reason why the same sqlite database is 5-10X slower on iOS 5 for the same query.

This also appears to slow down core data applications that use sqlite as a backing store.

In my case, the same application running on iOS 4.0 on an iPhone 3GS is markedly faster than the same application running on an iPhone 4S with iOS 5.

edit:
I tried some performance modifications as listed in the following post, but nothing resulted in a significant performance change.
[Improve INSERT-per-second performance of SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711631/how-do-i-improve-the-performance-of-sqlite)

Comment: Which query do you profile? Select or Insert?

Comment: In this case, it is a simple select with a where clause using only indexed columns.

Comment: Have you run with Instruments to quantify where the CPU burn is (presuming it's CPU, and not flash latency, iCloud sync or god knows what).

Comment: Yes, this is all still valid on a fresh project that does nothing but a sqlite query. All of the sqlite functions seem to take longer, most of all the step function (although that one is also called more).